# Git add not working with pasted in folder

Tags: git

So I cloned a repo, and then pasted in a folder that I was working on, tried to add and then commit and push.

When I check the remote repo, none of the files seem to have been pushed.

When I run git status I see this -

```
    #
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   ReviewApp (modified content)
#
```

I've tried going through and adding files in each subfolder, I've also tried doing a git add ., and I've checked the .gitignore.

I'm not sure why I can't add this modified content and push.

Can anyone help?

Comment: if you put `git add .` and then `git status` what do you get?

Comment: that's the only modfied file?

Comment: yeah- so I also tried this. I copied the folder over, then went inside  and did git branch - I was back on master for some reason, as opposed to the new branch I had checked out

Comment: Have you tried cloning it again and updating just that file? and commit, push normally?

Comment: it's a large folder - I've tried cloning the repo again, and then pasted the folder in, then checked out a new local branc

Comment: It looks like a submodule. Did you mean this to be a submodule? If not you need to move the `.git` folder in `ReviewApp` out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

> When I check the remote repo, none of the files seem to have been pushed.

It is possible the files were push (if you didn't see "everything up-to-date" when pushing, that means *something* were pushed), but on another branch (different from the one you see by default on the remote side, which is generally `master`)

Check the full history with a:

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --branches
```

To check if the history reflects the addition of that folder (because of that folder has been aded and committed, any subsequent `git add .` would not change that, and the status will only show you one modified gile)